# Can someone give an example of auth.getSession for facebook dev?

Tags: facebook

I have the auth token generated. I need to get the infinite session using that. So i wanna know the parameters to be passed for auth.getSession. A simple code for the complete flow is appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Facebook does not allow infinite session now. You have to request the user to give you extra permission to get infinite session from facebook.

Answer (score 0):

They do allow infinite sessions. It's just called something else: http://www.emcro.com/blog/2009/01/facebook-infinite-session-keys-no-more/

Answer (score 0):

You can create infinite session in Facebook. The below link will be helpful:

http://www.app-developers.com/index.php?topic=23.0